# Interchange of set theoretical limit

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Find for what type of real valued measurable functions g, the equality holds:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \{x: |g(x)|>a-1/n\}= \{x: |g(x)| \geq a\}$$ where $a \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a \geq 0$ and $g: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ any function. I don't think we need measurability here since we do not measure anything.

Set $A_{g,n} := \{x: |g(x)| > a - 1/n\}$ and $A_g := \{x: |g(x)| \geq a\}$. For the sequence of sets $(A_{g,n})_{n \geq 1}$, we have two notions of limits:

- $\overline{A}:= \limsup_{n \to \infty} A_{g,n} := \bigcap_{n \geq 1} \bigcup_{k \geq n}A_{g,k}\quad$ and
- $\underline{A} := \liminf_{n \to \infty} A_{g,n} := \bigcup_{n \geq 1} \bigcap_{k \geq n}A_{g,k}$

If $\overline{A} = \underline{A}$, we call this set $A$ and write $A = \lim_{n \to \infty} A_{g,n}$.

For all $n \geq 1$, it holds that $A_{g,n+1} \subset A_{g, n}\,$, i.e.  $(A_{g,n})_{n \geq 1}$ is nonincreasing. In this case, we have (why?)

$$
{\displaystyle \liminf _{n\rightarrow \infty }A_{g,n}=\bigcup _{n\geq 1}\bigcap _{k\geq n}A_{g,k}=\bigcap _{k\geq 1}A_{g,k}=\bigcap _{n\geq 1}\bigcup _{k\geq n}A_{g,k}=\limsup _{n\rightarrow \infty }A_{g,n}.}
$$

So, $\overline{A} = \underline{A}$ and  $A = \lim_{n \to \infty} A_{g,n} = \bigcap_{k \geq 1} A_{g,k}$. But this intersection exactly yields $A_g$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g: X \to \mathbb{R}$ be any function. Given any $a \geqslant 0$, we have that, for all $n \in \Bbb N$, $n \geqslant 1$,

$$ \left \{x: |g(x)|>a-1/(n+1) \right \} \subseteq \left \{x: |g(x)|>a-1/n \right \}   $$

So $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \{x: |g(x)|>a-1/n\}= \bigcap_{n \geqslant 1} \{x: |g(x)|>a-1/n\} = \{x: |g(x)| \geqslant a\}$$